# DJI Assistant 2 not compatable with Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, wine

I need to upgrade the firmware on my DJI Phantom 4 Pro.

I need to load *DJI Assistant 2* and then connect it to my drone for the firmware upgrade. I tried to with WINE, but the *.exe* file from *DJI Assistant* doesn't want to work via WINE. Next step would be to try VirtualBox, but I don't have a Windows subscription. Also, I have read that it might slow my laptop down badly.

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell laptop.

Any advice would be much appreciated.